# Objective-C message syntax

Tags: objective-c

while learning Objective-C I stumbled across the following code, which I do not understand:

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[self.navigationController topViewController];
```

As far as I understand

```
[self.navigationController topViewController]
```

is sending the message (calling the method) `topViewController` to `self.navigationController`.

Looking in the .h File I only find `topViewController`being a property, not a function:

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) UIViewController *topViewController; // The top view controller on the stack.
```

Can somebody explain what is happening there?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually, I would go for Swift

Comment: @Teejay How does that contribute??? It's just a random statement.

Comment: @Popeye Nope, it's an advice. Why learn a language that seems to be as good as dead?

Comment: @Teejay Since when is objective-c as good as dead???? Please provide where it says this because that is just a stupid and redundant comment and contributes in no way.

Comment: Yeah, learning Swift is definitely a goal. But to understand iOS development in general I realized that there is no way around learning Objective-C at the moment. (At least some basics...)

Comment: @beeches Yes, you're absolutely right. My comment was just a "provocation".

Comment: @Popeye Probably you didn't see the WWDC keynote. They didn't state that, but it was implicit that Obj-C will die **sooner or later**, when Swift will be completely mature.

Comment: @Teejay assumption are a bad thing if they haven't stated it then it isn't true and just going off your assumption isn't he way it works.

Comment: @Popeye No one in the past probably stated that VB6 was dying, of course you can still use it. But I would say it's dead, wouldn't you?

Comment: @Teejay that doesn't make a difference. Unless Apple make it official and say objective-c see is now dead and redundant you shouldn't be basing your comments/answers on assumptions as you are providing incorrect advise. You could turn around and say Java will be dead in 6 months time because someone introduced a new language but it doesn't mean that java is going to die off that is just a comment from someone. So until Apple make it official it is still a valid language and you should be answering as though it will not die out.

Comment: @Popeye So, is learning a brand-new language, rather than a 20y old one (incidentally horrible one) a bad advice?

Comment: @Teejay I don't think objective-c is a horrible language so yes I would consider it bad. Just because you think something is bad doesn't mean everyone else does. I don't like coffee but others do but it doesn't mean it's bad just because I don't like it. You have no argument at all, everything you say is based on your opinion and have nothing to back it up to say forget about objective-c its dead.

Comment: @Popeye Adjective "horrible" was "incidentally". Horrible or not, it's 20y old and misses most modern patterns of other languages.

Comment: @Popeye If you look around, all class courses are going in the swift direction.

Comment: @Teejay just because something is old doesn't mean it's dead Java is over 20 years old doesn't that make it dead too? Please provide comments and answers with facts not just your opinion.

Comment: @Popeye I just gave an advice. Advices are primarly opinion-based. BTW, Java has been modernized during the years much more that Obj-C has. You should consider Swift as Obj-C 2, not just a new language. So why use Java 5 if Java 6 is available (when builing something new) ?

Comment: @Teejay Well since obj-c 2 is just obj-c since there was a previous version of obj-c so it has been updated as well. And there has never been and as of yet apple have never implied that swift will ever take over obj-c stop basing everything on your own opinions at the moment swift is just an alternative (Which is what Apple have said) to obj-c

Comment: @Popeye Apple is famous for imposing standards and abandoning old technologies. We'll see... BTW, I repeat, mine was just an advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either syntax is fine:

```
[self.navigationController topViewController]
```

and:

```
self.navigationController.topViewController
```

The latter is calling the property's *getter* method, which probably looks like this:

```
- (UIViewController *)topViewController
{
    return _topViewController;
}
```

I would prefer the latter if it's been defined as a `@property`.

Answer (score 1):

The "dot syntax" is another way of calling a method (only methods that do not have any arguments may be called this way).

So the statement:

```
[self.navigationController topViewController]
```

is actually interpreted as:

```
[[self navigationController] topViewController]
```

which means:

- The message `navigationController` is sent to the object `self`.
- The message `topViewController` is sent to the object that was returned by `navigationController`.

A property itself is just a fancy way of defining methods. A readonly property only provides a getter (`foo`), a read/write property also provides a setter (`setFoo:`). By default, the compiler generates these methods to access an also implicitly defined variable `_foo`.

Answer (score 1):

A property is really a convention that means you have ivars with accessor methods, setters and getters, that meet a standard style and provides additional functionality that is derived from the conventional style.

With Objective-C 2.0 we got synthesized properties.  That is the compiler will generate a lot of boilerplate code to make ivars and associated setter and getter methods for you that adhere to conventions and provide most importantly consistent memory management and KVC and KVO. (Google those separately).

It also brought the dot syntax, which is syntactic sugar, in other words the compiler interprets it the same way as corresponding bracket syntax.

Both dot and bracket syntax are transformed the same way by the compiler into the same kinds of calls.

There is no functional difference.